# Attempting to reference a deleted function error when swapping priority queues

Tags: c++, priority-queue, deleted-functions

I was just trying to swap the data between the two priority queues and got this error. I also did some googling and still don't know what's wrong here.

```
#include <queue>

class Node
{
public:
    int idx;
};
auto greater = []( const Node& a, const Node&  b) {return a.idx > b.idx; };
using QUEUE  = std::priority_queue<Node, std::vector<Node>, decltype(greater)>;

void foo(QUEUE& a)
{
    QUEUE b(greater);
    a.swap(b);
}

int main()
{

}
```

Here's the full error message:

> Error C2280   ' < lambda_07efac20ebfa61cc8bb35aebd7d81f7c> &<<
>   lambda_07efac20ebfa61cc8bb35aebd7d81f7c>>::operator =(const <<
>   lambda_07efac20ebfa61cc8bb35aebd7d81f7c>> &)': attempting to reference
>   a deleted function

Comment: Seems to be a quirk in Visual Studio. This code compiles fine on my machine (clang-802.0.42).

Comment: @Vol If so, it's also a quirk of GCC 5.1.0.

Comment: @NeilButterworth standard library implementation plays a role here. Does not compile with libstdc++, but compiles with libc++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation of `std::swap` in stdlibc++ (and, most likely, standard library for Visual Studio) uses old-fashioned assignments:

```
swap(_Tp& __a, _Tp& __b)
{
    // concept requirements
    __glibcxx_function_requires(_SGIAssignableConcept<_Tp>)

    _Tp __tmp = __a;
    __a = __b;
    __b = __tmp;
}
```

On the contrary, libcxx implements it using `std::move`:

```
swap(_Tp& __x, _Tp& __y) _NOEXCEPT_(is_nothrow_move_constructible<_Tp>::value &&
                                    is_nothrow_move_assignable<_Tp>::value)
{
     _Tp __t(_VSTD::move(__x));
     __x = _VSTD::move(__y);
     __y = _VSTD::move(__t);
}
```

In order to swap objects of type `std::priority_queue` you have to swap their comparators, which are represented as a lambda in your code. Swapping lambda in stdlibc++ is impossible due to deleted copy assignment operator.

By the way, there is no need to use a lambda since your capture list is empty. A simple function will do the job.

```
bool greater(const Node& a, const Node&  b) {return a.idx > b.idx;};
using QUEUE = std::priority_queue<Node, std::vector<Node>, decltype(&greater)>;

void foo(QUEUE&& a)
{
    QUEUE b(&greater);
    a.swap(b);
}
```

Alternatively, you can replace a lambda with a callable object which has move assignment.

Answer (score 3):

Lambdas don't have assignment operators, and swap() uses assignment. It will be trying to use assignment on the greater lambda held inside the queue.